# ListView exceeding parent area

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm using `ListView` and I'm loading that onto a `Rectangle`. While scrolling the content up or down the content is not correctly hidden and remains visible to the user. Can someone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reported by the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html):

> Note: Views **do not enable clip automatically**. If the view is not clipped by another item or the screen, it will be necessary to set clip: true in order to have the out of view items clipped nicely.

Hence, what you are experiencing is a common behaviour and you should either 1) clip the view via other `Item`s (e.g. a header `Rectangle` and a footer `Rectangle` with `z:infinite` or simply set the `clip` property to `true`, i.e.

```
ListView{
   //...
   clip:true
   //...
}
```

Clipping has some [perfomance disavantages](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html#clipping) which can greatly affect the application as it grows. Hence, its usage, especially outside the views scenario, should be evaluated carefully.

Comment: np it is my pleasure to help :)