# Qml Flickable overwrite content

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I tried to enable scrolling of the content in my application using a `Flickable`.
Now content is scrollable, but content hides the top content.

Code:

```
Flickable {
    anchors.top: pageMessagesHeader.bottom
    anchors.topMargin: 20

    boundsBehavior: Flickable.DragOverBounds
    contentHeight: contentItem.childrenRect.height
    contentWidth: contentItem.childrenRect.width
    height: 500
    width: 400
    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}

    Rectangle {
        color: "white"
        height: 1000
        width: 400
        id: listMessages
    }

    }
```

[image: Before scroll]

[image: After]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListView exceeding parent area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40482081/listview-exceeding-parent-area)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.8/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#details) you can find a sentence:

> Flickable **does not automatically clip its contents**. If it is not used as a full-screen item, you should consider **setting the clip property** to true.

Which is the solution.

Just add

```
clip: true
```

to your code, and you'll be good.

Clipping has some [perfomance disavantages](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html#clipping) which can greatly affect the application as it grows. Hence, its usage, especially outside the views scenario, should be evaluated carefully.

Comment: It was so easy! Thanks a lot!

Comment: That property is a pain the neck, really. ;) Mark this comment as "too chatty" once you've read it.